# Работа с django-fromset-js

Tags: django

Суть задачи.
Каталог реализован на django.
У каждого Appliance может быть произвольное количество прикрепленных картинок с описанием. Для этого была создана модель ApplianceImage

*models.py*

```
class Appliance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=400, unique=True,  verbose_name='Название прибора')
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_numbers = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='ID код прибора')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание')
    tech_details = models.TextField(verbose_name='Технические данные')
    contents_of_delivery = models.CharField(max_length=400, verbose_name='Комплектация поставки')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Прибор')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Приборы')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ApplianceImage(models.Model):
     appliance = models.ForeignKey(Appliance, null=True, blank=True, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/img', verbose_name='Изображение')
     description = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Описание изображения', default='')

     class Meta:
         verbose_name = ('Изображение')
         verbose_name_plural = ('Изображения')

     def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

*forms.py*

```
     class Meta:
        model = Appliance
        fields = ['name', 'section', 'id_numbers', 'description', 'tech_details', 'contents_of_delivery']


class ApplianceImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

        class Media(object):
            js = formset_media_js + (
                # Other form media here
            )

        class Meta:
            model = ApplianceImage
            exclude = ['appliance']

MyFormSet = formset_factory(ApplianceImageForm, can_delete=True, can_order=True)
```

пробую реализовать через django-formset-js

*views.py*

```
    appliance_form = ApplianceForm()
    new_formset=MyFormSet()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_formset=MyFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES)


        if appliance_form.is_valid() :
            new_appliance = ApplianceForm(request.POST)

            for form in new_formset:
               form.appliance = new_appliance
               form.save()
            new_appliance.save()

        return redirect(catalog_appliance)


    return render(request, 'catalogapp/appliance_add.html', {
        'form': appliance_form,
        'formset' : new_formset
    })
```

_appliance_add.html_

```
  <div class="card-body">
        <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% bootstrap_form form %}
          <hr>
        {{ formset.media }}
        {{ formset.management_form }}

        <div id="formset" data-formset-prefix="{{ formset.prefix }}">

            <div data-formset-body>
                <!-- New forms will be inserted in here -->
                {% for form in formset %}
                    <div data-formset-form  >
                        {{ form }}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <!-- The empty form template. By wrapping this in a <script> tag, the
            __prefix__ placeholder can easily be replaced in both attributes and
            any scripts -->
            <script type="form-template" data-formset-empty-form    >
              {% escapescript %}
                  <div data-formset-form>
                      {{ formset.empty_form }}
                  </div>
              {% endescapescript %}
            </script>

            <!-- This button will add a new form when clicked-->
            <script>jQuery(function($) {
                  $("#formset").formset({
                      animateForms: true
                  });
              });
            </script>
        </div>
```

JS скрипт django-formset-js:
https://github.com/pretix/django-formset-js/blob/master/djangoformsetjs/static/js/jquery.formset.js

При попытке добавить поля формы, заполнить их и отправить получаю ошибку
'validationerror: ['данные управляющей формы отсутствуют или были повреждены']'

Comment: Пришлите отрендереннный вариант страницы

Comment: К сожалению не нашел ответа на заданный мною вопрос, но решил ситуацию тем, что отказался от  django-fromset-js в пользу  django-dynamic-formset.
С ним все пошло как по маслу.